# Get images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a method to assign six images to each player as follows:

```
public void AddCards(Player one, Player two)
{
        one.Images.Add(Card1Player);
        one.Images.Add(Card2Player);
        one.Images.Add(Card3Player);
        one.Images.Add(Card4Player);
        one.Images.Add(Card5Player);
        one.Images.Add(Card6Player);

        two.Images.Add(Card1Computer);
        two.Images.Add(Card2Computer);
        two.Images.Add(Card3Computer);
        two.Images.Add(Card4Computer);
        two.Images.Add(Card5Computer);
        two.Images.Add(Card6Computer);
}
```

My xaml file contains these images:

```
<Image Name="Card1Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="259,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
<Image Name="Card2Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="369,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
<Image Name="Card3Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="158,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
<Image Name="Card4Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="478,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
<Image Name="Card5Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="59,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
<Image Name="Card6Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="581,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" />
```

Same for the other six cards.

Is it possible to do this in a better way? I was thinking about something like creating a parent for each six Images and then getting the images from that. I don't know if this is possible.

I could also change the AddCards method to something like this:

```
public void AddCards(Player one, Player two)
{
        one.Images.AddRange(new List<Image>() { Card1Player, Card2Player});
        two.Images.AddRange(new List<Image>() { Card1Computer, Card2Computer});
}
```

It would be neat to get all images from the xaml without specifying all those names. Thats why I was thinking about a container / parent for those images.

Comment: MVVM does this better AFAIK. Try to google some article on it. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put it in Grid, specify a name for it e.g. PlayerImagesGrid than you may use something like this

```
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(PlayerImagesGrid); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(PlayerImagesGrid, i);
        var image = child as Image;

        if (image != null)
        {
            one.Images.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

It's not so neat but you need not worry about extensibility.
Also you may remove images names if you do not use them anywhere else.